# creating bitmap in Asynctask freeze UI

Tags: android, multithreading, bitmap, android-asynctask

I am attempting to create new bitmap in asynctask so it wont Freeze my UI,
I use the execute method in onActivityResult()

```
   @Override
    protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
        super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
        if(resultCode==RESULT_OK) {
            if(requestCode == GALLERY_RESAULT || requestCode == CAPTURE_RESAULT) {
                Uri uri;
                if (data != null) {
                    uri = data.getData();
                    photoURI=null;
                }
                else uri = photoURI;
                // THIS IS MY ASYNC TASK
                new BitmapGetter().execute(uri);
            }
        }
    }
```

And all the expansive work, such as creating new bitmap I do INSIDE the doInBackground() method and still its freeze my UI, any suggestion?
The whole AsyncTask:

```
class BitmapGetter extends AsyncTask<Uri,Void,Bitmap>{
        long startTime;
        private Bitmap composeImage(Bitmap bitmap){
            Log.d("image","TAGGGGGGGGG   "+bitmap.getHeight()+"  "+bitmap.getWidth() +"      "+(startTime-Calendar.getInstance().getTimeInMillis()));
            int divide =0;
            float density = getResources().getDisplayMetrics().density;
            while(bitmap.getWidth()/density/(divide+1) > 150 &&bitmap.getHeight()/density/(divide+1) > 150  )
                divide++;
            if(divide==0)
                divide++;
            bitmap=Bitmap.createScaledBitmap(bitmap,bitmap.getWidth()/divide,bitmap.getHeight()/divide,true);
            Log.d("image","TAGGGGGGGGG   "+bitmap.getHeight()+"  "+bitmap.getWidth()+"         "+(startTime-Calendar.getInstance().getTimeInMillis()));
            try {
                String fileName = String.valueOf(Calendar.getInstance().getTimeInMillis());
                tempImageFile = new File(getApplicationContext().getFilesDir().getAbsolutePath()+"/"+fileName+".jpg");
                Log.d("image","NEW FILE   "+tempImageFile.getAbsolutePath()+"   "+(startTime-Calendar.getInstance().getTimeInMillis()));
                Uri fileUri = Uri.fromFile(tempImageFile);
                OutputStream outputStream =  getContentResolver().openOutputStream(fileUri);
                if(ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(getApplicationContext(),Manifest.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE)==PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
                    bitmap.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG, 80, outputStream);
                    outputStream.flush();
                    outputStream.close();
                    photoLocation= tempImageFile.getAbsolutePath();
                    Log.d("image","DONE WRITE TO NEW FILE   "+tempImageFile.getAbsolutePath()+"   "+(startTime-Calendar.getInstance().getTimeInMillis()));

                }else{
                    requestPermissions(new String[]{Manifest.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE},1);
                }
            } catch (FileNotFoundException e1) {
                e1.printStackTrace();
            } catch (IOException e1) {
                e1.printStackTrace();
            }
            return  bitmap;
        }

        @Override
        protected Bitmap doInBackground(Uri... params) {
            Cursor c=null;
            startTime=Calendar.getInstance().getTimeInMillis();
            Log.d("image","STARTTTTTTTTTTTTTTTTTTT    "+Calendar.getInstance().getTimeInMillis());
            if(photoURI==null){
             c = getApplicationContext().getContentResolver().query(params[0],new String[]{MediaStore.Images.Media.DATA},null,null,null);
            if(c.moveToFirst()){
                photoLocation = c.getString(c.getColumnIndex(MediaStore.Images.ImageColumns.DATA));
                photoURI = params[0];
                 }
            } else {
                c = getApplicationContext().getContentResolver().query(MediaStore.Images.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI,new String[]{MediaStore.Images.Media.DATA},null,null,null);
                if(c.moveToLast()){
                    photoLocation = c.getString(c.getColumnIndex(MediaStore.Images.ImageColumns.DATA));
                }
            }
            if(photoLocation==null){
                return null;
            }
            Log.d("image","FOUND PHOTOO    "+(startTime-Calendar.getInstance().getTimeInMillis()));

            ExifInterface e=null;
            try {
                 e = new ExifInterface(photoLocation);
                Log.d("image","CREATED ORIENTATION    "+(startTime-Calendar.getInstance().getTimeInMillis()));
            } catch (IOException e1) {
                e1.printStackTrace();
            }
            int rotation = e.getAttributeInt(ExifInterface.TAG_ORIENTATION,ExifInterface.ORIENTATION_NORMAL);
            Bitmap bitmap= BitmapFactory.decodeFile(photoLocation);
            Matrix matrix = new Matrix();
            if(rotation!=ExifInterface.ORIENTATION_NORMAL)
                switch (rotation){
                    case ExifInterface.ORIENTATION_ROTATE_90:
                        matrix.preRotate(90);
                        break;
                    case ExifInterface.ORIENTATION_ROTATE_180:
                        matrix.preRotate(180);
                        break;
                    case ExifInterface.ORIENTATION_ROTATE_270:
                        matrix.preRotate(270);
                        break;
                }else{
                Log.d("image","NORMAL ORIENTATION    "+(startTime-Calendar.getInstance().getTimeInMillis()));
                return composeImage(bitmap);
            }
            Log.d("image","CREATE NEW ORIENTATION    "+(startTime-Calendar.getInstance().getTimeInMillis()));
            bitmap = Bitmap.createBitmap(bitmap,0,0,bitmap.getWidth(),bitmap.getHeight(),matrix,true);
            Log.d("image","FINISHED CREATING NEW ORIENTATION    "+(startTime-Calendar.getInstance().getTimeInMillis()));
            return composeImage(bitmap);
        }

        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(Bitmap bitmap) {
            Log.d("image","SET BITMAP   "+tempImageFile.getAbsolutePath()+"   "+(startTime-Calendar.getInstance().getTimeInMillis()));
            if(bitmap!=null)
                mImageView.setImageBitmap(bitmap);
            Log.d("image","FINISHEDDDDDDDD   "+tempImageFile.getAbsolutePath()+"   "+(startTime-Calendar.getInstance().getTimeInMillis()));
        }
    }
```

Comment: You are not only constructing a bitmap but also writing the bitmap as jpg to file? Why?

Comment: `Log.d("image","FINISHEDDDDDDDD ....` You are alseo logging that when bitmap==null. Better have different logs in that case. You could use Toast() too to inform the user.

Comment: I'm puzzled why that would freeze the GUI.

Comment: The code it's a little bit hard to understand. You just need to load a image into a imageView?

Comment: @adalPaRi
I am loading a image user pick form gallary / capture with camera.
later the user can choose to upload it to the server so i also save resized and composed image to a tempfile that will be deleted after the upload.

Comment: @greenapps ^ top comment explain it